# Add Button on top of "img-responsive" div with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

In my webpage, I've created a div and added the class "img-responsive" to it. It works extremely well and scales perfectly. However, I need to add a button on top of it and the only way I have done that so far is using the CSS property "position:absolute" and defining it's position. That does work, but when I resize my browser, the button will not scale with the webpage and is hidden on smaller screens. How can I fix this?

Here's the image of what the header of my page looks like: http://postimg.org/image/xdols29nn/

This is what my div looks like:

```
<div style="position:relative;" class="img-responsive" >
        <img src="images/mac2.png" width="1440" class="img-responsive" >
            <div>

                    <input style="position:absolute; left: 1130px; top:35px;"type="button" value="Button" href="#sidr" id="simple-menu">

            </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just doing this (making your button and then your image width:100%).  This will force them both to be responsive with the same width of whatever container they are in without requiring any positioning.:

```
<div class='row'>
    <button class='btn btn-default' style='width:100%;'>button</button>
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzY2NiIvPjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNDQ0O2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+U2Vjb25kIHNsaWRlPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==" style='width:100%;height:auto;' />
</div>
```

Let me know if I'm on the wrong track.